# Can I create related filtered tables in Looker Studio?

Tags: dashboard, looker-studio

I'm currently doing a dashboard with Looker Studio. I have a BigQuery database connected to it so i get the data from that database.

What I need is to know how to create some filtered related tables. For example: if you have a table with the terms Vegetables (1), Fruits (2) and Cars (3) and the user select Fruits, another table with all types of cars, fruits and vegetables must filter all its data to show only the fields with the related ID (2).

I know Looker Studio filters the data automatically when there's 2 or more table and you select one field, but it does in this way: if you select Fruits, the filter will try to find Fruits in other tables, not relating its ID.

Do someone know the way to do it properly? Thanks!

Comment: Do the 2 tables have the same columns, especially the ones you want to use as filters?